# Version increment happening for multiple reads for LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT using Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So my setup is:

- Java Framework: Spring JPA
- Backend Database: Postgres

```
@Override
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)
Optional<User> findById(UUID id);
```

I am trying to add locking to my existing code base. I have introduced a version column for the same and added @Transaction annotation to my method/s.

However, there are flows where the data is read multiple times, and I noticed that every time the data is read, the version is incremented. Since this is all in same transaction, I do not expect version/s to get incremented (unless I do a save to DB). Is my expectation wrong ? Can someone help me understand what I am missing here?